# What are the best ways to pass IIS Site Name to the JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, iis

I'm developing now ASP.NET Core MVC application with Razor pages, where one of the requirements is to keep all JavaScript functions in a separate file.

In the JS function I'm sending a **POST** request to some endpoint, after receiving successful response I want to redirect the application to another page.

```
function onRowClick(e) {
    var dbkey = e.data === undefined ? 0 : e.data.DBKey;

    if (dbkey != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/test/ValidateDataInEndpointY",
            type: "POST",
            data: { selectedProjectDBkey: dbkey },
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.href =  "/test2/GoToPageX";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I'm using Visual Studio or custom IIS WebSite everything works.The application url in VS/IIS is build like `https://localhost:1234/` and the AJAX requests are using proper endpoint/page address - `https://localhost:1234/test/...`

But when I deployed the application to IIS and added it to the Default Web Site as a new application (using Convert to Application function) and created new application address -> `http://localhost/myApplicationName`, the AJAX request stopped working.

[image]

It do not take the `myApplicationName` into consideration, and builds the url of the endpoint like `https://localhost/test/...` instead of `https://localhost/myApplicationName/test/...`.

What is the best way to handle the Site name and base URL here? I've tried to use different solutions in the JS file - windows.location, document.location, passing the parameter from the Razor page like below, and nothing worked. Everytime I'm just getting the localhost without the site name.

```
<script>
   var baseUrl = somefunctionhere;
</script>
```

Data returned by `document.location`:

[image]

At this moment I have a workaround - I define the base URL in the JavaScript file, but I assume it's not the best solution. Also, if not needed I do not want to get the Site information from backend on the server.

Comment: I don't think there is a best way, you can choose the method that suits your project, may be you can try to use the UrlHelper class to generate URLs in your views, e.g. @Url.Action(), then if you need them in a javascript file, pass them as a parameter to a javascript function.